# Memory Leak with NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, nsxmlparser

I'm writing an app that uses an NSXMLParser to parse info from a website and then store it in my app. I am releasing the parser that I create in my @finally block but Instruments is still showing it as a memory leak. The app's behavior, aside from this, is perfect. Here's the code:

```
NSXMLParser *myParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL]; //<--memory leak

@try {

    if (myParser != nil)
    {
        [myParser setDelegate:self];
        [myParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
        [myParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
        [myParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    }

    [myParser parse];

}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"%@, %@",[e name], [e reason]);
}
@finally {
    [xmlURL release];
    [myParser release];
}
```

Any recommendations as to why this is showing up as a memory leak?

**EDIT*****

Below is the delegate method I've implemented in my code:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI
(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Cube"])
{
    if ([attributeDict objectForKey:@"time"])
    {
        NSArray *pathsArray =
        NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *path = [pathsArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *timePlistPath = [NSString stringWithString:
            [path stringByAppendingString:@"/time.plist"]];

        NSString *TimeString = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"time"];
        [TimeString writeToFile:timePlistPath atomically:YES
            encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:nil];
    }

    if ([attributeDict objectForKey:@"currency"] && [attributeDict objectForKey:@"rate"])
    {
        NSString *currencyObject = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"currency"];
        NSString *rateObject = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"rate"];
        [mAryCurrency addObject:currencyObject];
        [mAryRates addObject:rateObject];
    }
}
```

}

Could this be the cause of the leak?

Comment: Everything is correct in your posted code. It's probably something in the NSXMLParserDelegate's callbacks. Try to comment the code in those method and see if leak still exists.

Answer (score 0):

It's because it's in `@finally` probably, when it's checking its most likely assuming `@finally` won't get called, if its showing up as a leak in Build & Analyze, I would ignore it.

Even Apple recommends releasing in `@finally`:

```
    - (void)doSomething {

    NSMutableArray *anArray = nil;

    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    @try {

        [self doSomethingElse:anArray];

    }

    @finally {

        [anArray release];

    }
}
```

Comment: @finally {
    [xmlURL release];
    [myParser release];
} - have you seen that?